# Steam c# login error

Tags: c#, api, authentication, rsa, steam

Hi guys i have problem with login to a steam
I've tried many classes and every time i got same problem that my login/password is bad
So I've tried to write my own class and same pass/login error :c

> {"success":false,"requires_twofactor":false,"message":"The account
>   name or   password that you have entered is
>   incorrect.","clear_password_field":true, 
>   "captcha_needed":false,"captcha_gid":-1}

I've tried many ways to encrypt password 
but finaly I have tried to use same publickey_exp and publickey_mod as the script on a steam login page
but when i use same rsa parameters the returned string is different that the page returned anyone has an idea (sorry for mistakes) :D

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace SteamLogin {
    class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {



        CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();

        string login = "MyLogin";//this what i must type to login box on a steam page for example "gaben"
        string pass = "abcdefghijk";//this what i must type to password box on a steam page "thebestpassword"
        double seconds = GetSeconds();

        string buf = doRequestPost("donotcache=" + seconds +
            "&username=" + login, "https://steamcommunity.com/login/getrsakey/", ref cookies);


        dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(buf);

        buf = "";

        if (stuff.success != "true") {
            Console.WriteLine("getrsakey error");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;

        }


        string publickey_exp = stuff.publickey_exp;
        string publickey_mod = stuff.publickey_mod;
        string timestamp = stuff.timestamp;
        string passEncrypted;



        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()) {

            RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters {
                Exponent = HexStringToByteArray(publickey_exp),
                Modulus = HexStringToByteArray(publickey_mod)
            };

            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
            byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass), false);
            passEncrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);

            Console.WriteLine(passEncrypted);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }



        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Logging In...");



        Console.WriteLine(doRequestPost("donotcache=" +
            GetSeconds() + "&password=" + 
            passEncrypted + "&username=" +
            login + "&twofactorcode=&emailauth=&loginfriendlyname=&captchagid=-1&captcha_text=&emailsteamid=&rsatimestamp=" +
            timestamp + "&remember_login=false", "https://steamcommunity.com/login/dologin/", ref cookies));



        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static double GetSeconds() {
        TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
        return span.TotalSeconds;
    }

    public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString) {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(hexString.Length / 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2) {
            stream.WriteByte(byte.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    }

    static string doRequestPost(string postData, string url, ref CookieCollection cookies) {

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        foreach (Cookie cook in cookies)
            request.CookieContainer.Add(cook);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        cookies = response.Cookies;

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        response.Dispose();

        return responseString;

    }
}
}
```